# How Recursive types with no leaf cases can be accepted in OCaml?

Tags: recursion, types, ocaml

It is a well-known fact that OCaml rejects to define bare recursive types such as `type t = t -> int` and the Y-combinator example in [Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Y_combinator#OCaml) are not working as well.

However, recently I found that the little tweak of the recursive type definition like `type t = A of (t -> int)` works well. The following code is some proof-of-concept works to check which one works well.

```
(* OCaml version 4.08.0 *)
(* Precisely, ocaml-base-compiler.4.08.0 *)

# type t = t -> int;;
Error: The type abbreviation t is cyclic

# type t = int -> t;;
Error: The type abbreviation t is cyclic


# type t1 = A of (int -> t1);;
type t1 = A of (int -> t1)

# let v1 = 
    let rec f _ = A f in
    A f;;
val v1 : t1 = A <fun>


# type t2 = B of (t2 -> int);;
type t2 = B of (t2 -> int)

# let v2 =
    let g _ = 3 in
    B g;;
val v2 : t2 = B <fun>


# type t3 = C of (t3 -> t3);;
type t3 = C of (t3 -> t3)

# let v3 = 
    let rec h _ = C h in
    C h;;
val v3 : t3 = C <fun>
```

I know that the type can recursively appear to define algebraic data types like `list` or `tree` type, but they all have leaf cases such as `NIL` or `LEAF` constructor. Neither `t1`, `t2`, `t3` has leaf cases, but they are not rejected.

I have no clue to understand how the OCaml type system allows these kinds of type definitions. Could you explain why `t1`, `t2`, `t3` types are accepted and how to interpret the meaning of the values `v1`, `v2`, and `v3`? Is there any practical usage for recursive types which has no leaf cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Early versions of OCaml happily accepted types such as `type t = t -> int`. They even inferred them. The problem with that was that in most of the practical cases, such a type just masks a programming error. So by popular demand, they were disallowed, and you now need to need an explicit datatype. You can still get the old behaviour if you use the `-rectypes` option with the compiler.

That was merely a pragmatic decision. There is no semantic problem with such types, at least not in a language like OCaml.

Data types do not need to have non-recursive constructors as "leaf" cases, as long as the type of at least one constructor includes values that do not require another value of the defined type.

For example,

```
type 'a list1 = List1 of 'a * 'a list1 option
```

is a possible type to represent non-empty lists. That works, because it includes `List1 (x, None)` as a non-recursive value.

Functions are a similar example in that sense.